# Are fashion models sexy?

Tags: sexuality, beauty

*TL;DR: Is there a group of females beating fashion models in terms of sexiness?*

#### Initial motivation

This is a follow-up to [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/8288/16889) which seems to imply that top models are considered the norm of beauty/attractiveness in today’s Western culture:

> Closer to home, you need to look no further than [Botticelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus_(Botticelli)). His Venus is way plumper than today‘s top models:
>
> [image: Venere Botticelli]<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus_(Botticelli))</sup>

#### Claim A: Fashion models are not sexy

[This article](http://www.femininebeauty.info/sexy-fashion-models) by *Feminine Beauty* asks:

> In 14 of the 15 women addressed above [models of European descent from the top-25 sexy female models as per Models.com], masculinization or a relative lack of femininity is readily observed. The question is, who finds the women other than Josie Moran sexy to start with, let alone make a top-25 list?

The implied claim that these models are not sexy is not made outright in this article, but in a summary of this article [elswhere on the same site](http://www.femininebeauty.info/skinny-fashion-models):

> Yet, most of the top-ranked "sexy" fashion models are too masculine for the tastes of heterosexual men; […]

Both articles also note that (quote from the latter):

> Almost all of the top-25 sexy fashion models are not among the top-50 fashion models, […]

So, assuming that this statement is correct even the makers of the “top-25 sexy fashion models” list (yes, these are those the article describes as too masculine) do not consider them top fashion models.

#### Claim B: Fashion models are sexy

The idea that fashion models are a beauty ideal seems to be a view hold by many young females to the extent that this idea is documented in scientific publications, e.g., [J. Kevin Thompson and Leslie J. Heinberg – The Media’s Influence on Body Image Disturbance and Eating Disorders: We’ve Reviled Them, Now Can We Rehabilitate Them?](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/0022-4537.00119) report the results of respective studies (I have no access to the cited papers):

> For example, in a study by Nichter and Nichter (1991), adolescent girls endorsed their ideal as the models found in fashion magazines aimed at teenage girls.
>
> ---
>
> Of 3,452 women responding, 23% indicated that movie or television celebrities influenced their body image when they were young, and 22% endorsed the influence of fashion magazine models (Garner, 1997).

<sup>Note that I am not disputing these statements, which study the prevalence of the claim I am interested in, if at all.</sup>

Now, *beauty ideal* (or similar) is somewhat fuzzy, but for the purpose of having an investigateable statement (and only for this) it should be safe to say that sexual attractivity plays a sufficent part in it. The corresponding claim *Fashion models are sexy* would thus be the opposite of the above claim.

#### Question

Is there a study investigating claim A or B (and thus probably rejecting the respective other). Due to the impossibility of drawing a clear line between *sexy* and *not sexy,* this probably involves a comparison with a reasonable control group, for example a comparison between:

- Female models gaining high media attention, i.e., roughly super models or runway models [as categorised by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_(people)#Fashion_modelling), that are not explicitly termed plus-size or similar.
- A control group of females with a physiognomy that can be reasonably expected to beat fashion models in terms of sexiness, such as “plus-size” models, [“booth babes”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth_babe) (as sexiness is a more direct criterion for them), professional athletes or even random young females with healthy body weight.

Comment: You are honestly taking my comments way out of context. Please find an actual claim! Then ask a question as "This example [insert an example here] claims that western culture has a beauty norm of being thin. is it true?"

Comment: Do any experts even claim that fashion models are even supposed to be sexy? I think it is just something to show off cloths. From my understanding the research is pretty settled, skinny people are just universally considered ugly.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski: Experts probably don’t, but going by the studies referenced in the question a lot of young females actually believe this. So, “[a significant number of people believe it is true](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2507/16889)”.